# Adjust image and text in one line

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, swingworker

I have the following code:

```
  import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
  import javax.swing.*;

          import java.beans.*;
 import java.util.Random;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class ProgressBarDemo extends JPanel
                         implements ActionListener, 
                                    PropertyChangeListener {
private JProgressBar progressBar;
private JButton generateButton;
private JButton exceptionButton;
private JTextArea taskOutput;
private Task task;

class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    /*
     * Main task. Executed in background thread.
     */
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int progress = 0;
        //Initialize progress property.
        setProgress(0);
        while (progress < 100) {
            //Sleep for up to one second.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
            //Make random progress.
            progress += random.nextInt(10);
            setProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
        }
        return null;
    }
    /*
     * Executed in event dispatching thread
     */
    @Override
    public void done() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        generateButton.setEnabled(true);
        setCursor(null); //turn off the wait cursor
        taskOutput.append("Done!\n");
        JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
        newFrame.setVisible(true);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Task Complete");
        newFrame.add(label);
        newFrame.setSize(250, 250);
    }
}
public ProgressBarDemo() {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel labelpanel = new JPanel();

    JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.LEADING); 
    headerLabel.setText("TEST APPLICATION");  
    headerLabel.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,25));
    headerLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg","hiii");
    JLabel imgl=new JLabel(icon);
    labelpanel.add(imgl);
    labelpanel.add(headerLabel);

    imgl.setBounds(10,10, 150, 70);
    //Create the demo's UI.
    generateButton = new JButton("button1");
    generateButton.setActionCommand("button1");
    generateButton.addActionListener(this);
    generateButton.setBounds(50, 200, 150, 30);

    exceptionButton = new JButton("button2");
    exceptionButton.setActionCommand("button2");
    exceptionButton.addActionListener(this);
    exceptionButton.setBounds(50, 300, 150, 30);

    progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    progressBar.setValue(0);
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    //progressBar.setBounds(x, y, width, height)

    taskOutput = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    taskOutput.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
    taskOutput.setEditable(false);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    labelpanel.add(headerLabel);
    labelpanel.setVisible(true);
    add(labelpanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
   // panel.add(headerLabel);
    panel.add(generateButton);
   // panel.add(progressBar);
    panel.add(exceptionButton);
    labelpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelpanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    add(new JScrollPane(taskOutput), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(progressBar);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
}
/**
 * Invoked when the user presses the start button.
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    generateButton.setEnabled(false);
    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    //Instances of javax.swing.SwingWorker are not reusuable, so
    //we create new instances as needed.
    task = new Task();
    task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);

    task.execute();

}
/**
 * Invoked when task's progress property changes.
 */
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()) {
        int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
        progressBar.setValue(progress);
        taskOutput.append(String.format(
                "Completed %d%% of task.\n", task.getProgress()));
    } 
}
/**
 * Create the GUI and show it. As with all GUI code, this must run
 * on the event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ProgressBarDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new ProgressBarDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I have an image logo.jpg and text "TEST APPLICATION". I want both these in one line. WIth my above code,the image is on top and text in on next line. How should I modify this code to bring both on one line without affecting other elements present in the frame?

Answer (score 3):

JLabels can contain both an icon, and the text, so you can simply add them both to the same label:

```
JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("TEST APPLICATION", JLabel.LEADING); 
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg","hiii");
headerLabel.setIcon(icon);
```

And then you won't need `imgl` anymore.

As a side note, don't use absolute layout. You *will* run in to problems with that. Use layout managers instead.